# Table with a DropDownListFor inside every row in a Partial View .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm facing a problem with a table inside a partial view, where each row have an dropDownListFor for status list and a button "change status".

But my problem is, if i have 3 row's and change the status when the view model get to controller the selected satus is the status of first row and not the status changed on selected row.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AlterarEstadoAfericao(GestaoAfericoesViewModel model)
    {
        GestaoAfericoesDbo gestaoAfericoesDbo = new GestaoAfericoesDbo();

        DbUtil dbUtil = new DbUtil();
        string connectionString = dbUtil.generateConnectionString(Connections.Endpoint);

        IntranetDbContext db;
        db = new IntranetDbContext(connectionString);

        var idEstado = db.AF_Estado.Where(a => a.descricao.Equals(model.SelectedEstadoRow)).ToList().First();
        int id_estado = Convert.ToInt32(idEstado.id);

        try
        {
            var dbAF_afericao = db.AF_afericao.Find(model.idSelected);
            dbAF_afericao.id_estado_actual = Convert.ToInt32(id_estado);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch(SqlException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("/GestaoAfericoes");

    }
```

Partial View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AlterarEstadoAfericao", "Ferramentas", FormMethod.Post))
    {

    <table id="table" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Início</th>
            <th>Fim</th>
            <th>Origem</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model.listGestaoAfericoes != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.listGestaoAfericoes)
            {
                
                <tr id="@item.id">
                    <td id="id">@item.id</td>
                    <td>@item.descricao</td>
                    <td>@item.data_ini_afericao</td>
                    <td>@item.data_fim_afericao</td>
                    <td id="origem">@item.origem_afericao</td>
                    <td>@item.id_estado_actual</td>

                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idSelected, new { @Value = @item.id})

                    <td>Estado: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedEstadoRow, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.listEstados)</td>
                    <td>

                        @Html.ActionLink("Alterar Estado", "AlterarEstadoAfericao", null,
                           new { onclick = "return confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende alterar o estado?');", @class = "btn btn-info" })

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
    }
```

Anyone can help-me to resolve this question?

Greetings

Comment: Seems like you are binding every dropdown to the same property. When the framework performs it's model binding the first html element with name attribute "SelectedEstadoRow" will be binded to your property. I suggest you move the "SelectedEstadoRow" property from your model to "listGestaoAfericoes" class as property and use this statement `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.SelectedEstadoRow, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.listEstados)`. Mind that "item" is the variable from your for loop

Comment: I tried another aproch like i posted in answer below, but without success

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way to try a resolution to the problem, but no success.

Partial View:

```
 foreach (var item in Model.listGestaoAfericoes)
                {

                    <tr id="@item.id">
                        <td id="id">@item.id</td>
                        <td>@item.descricao</td>
                        <td>@item.data_ini_afericao</td>
                        <td>@item.data_fim_afericao</td>
                        <td id="origem">@item.origem_afericao</td>
                        <td>@item.id_estado_actual</td>

                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idSelected, new { @Value = @item.id })

                        <td>Estado: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.SelectedEstadoRow, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.listEstados)</td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Alterar Estado", "AlterarEstadoAfericao", new { item.id, item.SelectedEstadoRow },
                               new { onclick = "return confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende alterar o estado?');", @class = "btn btn-info" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Controller:

```
       public ActionResult AlterarEstadoAfericao(Decimal id, string SelectedEstadoRow)
    {
        GestaoAfericoesDbo gestaoAfericoesDbo = new GestaoAfericoesDbo();

        DbUtil dbUtil = new DbUtil();
        string connectionString = dbUtil.generateConnectionString(Connections.Endpoint);

        IntranetDbContext db;
        db = new IntranetDbContext(connectionString);

        var idEstado = db.AF_Estado.Where(a => a.descricao.Equals(SelectedEstadoRow)).ToList().First();
        int id_estado = Convert.ToInt32(idEstado.id);

        try
        {
            var dbAF_afericao = db.AF_afericao.Find(id);
            dbAF_afericao.id_estado_actual = Convert.ToInt32(id_estado);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("/GestaoAfericoes");

    }
```

The id came to controller with correct value, but SelectedEstadoRow have a null value on the controller.